# A confusion about the method of undetermined coef. and what is the motivation behind the given vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, binary-operations

In the [book](http://dlx.b-ok.org/genesis/1127000/b3bbba7fc0acd330143c328c6b446b8e/_as/[John_H._Hubbard,_Beverly_H._West_(auth.)]_Differe(b-ok.org).pdf) of *Differential Equations: A Dynamical Systems Approach: Ordinary Differential Equations* by West&Hubbard, at page 73, it is states for *the Method of Undetermined coefficients* that

> Consider the differential equation $x' = p(t)x + q(t)$. Suppose that
>   $q(t)$ is an element of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ of
>   junctions $f$, closed under the operation
>
> $$f \to f' - p(t) f$$
>   [...]

I'm really confused about the definiton of $V$ because, for example, the operation that is stated is a unary operation (I see only one input), so how can we define a vector space with a unary operation ? Moreover, I coulnd't understand how exactly show we determined when a given function $g$ is in $V$ or not. I mean as far as I understood, to check whether $g\in V$ or not, I need to check that $g' - p(t)g$ (where $p(t)$ is given in the ODE) is in $V$, but by authors' definition, to check whether $g' - p(t)g \in V$, I need to check whether $[g' - p(t)g]' - p(t)[g' - p(t)g] \in V$ or not..., so I really found this confusing and I'm not even sure that I understood the author correctly.

Therefore, I'm looking for some clarifications for this proposition.

Plus, what is the motivation behind this vector space ? I mean I couldn't see why do need "the guesses solutions" to a first order linear DEs to be in this space ?

**Edit:**

I have put a link of the book.

**Edit 2:**

Note that my main question is about the structure of $V$, and not about it's existance or something, so you can assume $V$ exists for the purpuse of the question.

Comment: I think he tried to get to the form $x=p(t)(x-g)+g'$.

Comment: @Emil Why ? I couldn't understand. By the way, do you mean $x = ...$ or $x' = ...$ ?

Comment: The vector space $V$ is not defined, it is rather assumed to exist.  Note that at p72 there is the qualification "when it can be applied" and on p75 it is noted that a system may be singular and have no solution and that your guess may be bad. The method works (p75) "whenever you can find a sufficiently large ...". You have to use prior knowledge or intelligent guesswork to identify a suitable $V$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: yes, sorry, lhs was supposed to be $x'$. It reminded me of a residual that's why I wrote it.

Comment: @MarkBennet Ok, but in the case when $V$ exists, how can I construct it ? I mean what kind of function will it contain ?

Comment: @MarkBennet and what is the binary operation on that vector space ?

Comment: It is a vector space of functions under addition with real or complex coefficients. So I think one of the examples in the book has the functions $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ as a basis. Work through the illustrative examples to see what is going on. Here, if $p(t)=1$ then $a\sin t+b\cos t \to a\cos t-b\sin t+a\sin t+b\cos t$ gives another function of the same form.

Answer (score 1):

The "unary operation", as you called it, is not going to be one of the operations of the vector space. More precisely, you have to find a vector space $(V, +, \cdot)$ such that 
$$
f\in V \quad \Rightarrow\quad Df \in V, $$ 
where $Df:=f' -p(x)f.$ (Verifying that this is indeed the case amounts exactly to the task that you "find confusing", unfortunately).

Let me make a toy model. Redefine $D$ as $Df:=f'$. The vector space $V$ of real polynomials is closed$^{[1]}$ under the operation $D$, because if $f$ is a polynomial, its derivative is again a polynomial. Notice that this space is infinite dimensional. If $n\in\mathbb N$, the vector space of polynomials of degree up to $n$ is finite dimensional and closed under $D$.

In general, constructing such vector spaces is difficult. The framework is called [spectral theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_ordinary_differential_equations).

---

[1] This choice of terminology is unfortunate, according to me. I would have said that $V$ is *invariant* under $D$.

Comment: So, given $p(x)$, for example, if $f(x) = sin(x)$, I need to show that $f' - p(x)f = c*f(x) = c*sin(x)$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e $V$ assumes $f$ as its basis ?

Comment: I mean in you example, $Df := f'$, I can show that $V$ is closed under $D$ by showing that $f'$ can be written as a linear combination of $t^i$ for $i=0,1,...$ because this is what a polynomial means.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean even if it is not properly phrased. If $V$ is spanned by the set $\{e_j\ :\ j\in J\}$, to show that it is closed under $D$ we need to show that for each $k\in J$ we can write $De_k$ as a linear combination of $e_j$. This is true and is a consequence of the linearity of $D$.

Comment: By the way, what if $f(x) = a cos(x) + b sin(x)$ ?  are $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$ my basis, or only $cos(x) + sin(x)$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas: The basis is $\{\cos x, \sin x\}$, of course. Recall the definition of "linear combination".

Comment: But why ? I mean from what the author states, I cannot see why we have to choose $\{\cos x, \sin x\}$ as our basis.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: It's an educated guess. The authors are trying their luck.